# Deactivate Update and Restart/Shut Down options on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update

So how can I disable those 2 options, or at minimum, change the default one to the one I had before the updates were installed?

With some regards from Microsoft, I've put the updates on manual with Group Policy Editor and changed almost all the other options, so I'll go there check updates once in a while when I remember and update it when I have time to restart it and have not anything important running.

Every time I want to hibernate the computer (default action), I just do Win+Left+Enter fast and "automatically". I don't even think while I do that. And yesterday I did it by an accident after an update and the computer shut down.... (I would restart it by night - restarted eariler... amazing). Now I updated it again to make some testing, and I don't seem to understand how the heck I can change that stupid default option. I'm using StartIsBack as Start Menu, btw, and I think it gets the options from the Power Menu or something like that because they're the same options (Alt+F4 after clicking on Desktop or taskbar) - so I guess the question would be how to change the default option there.

So how can I do it? Either change the default option even when those are available, or just deactivate them completely??? The options on Group Policy Editor only work up to Windows 7... I find nothing that changes this on Windows 10.

Note: I'm using build 1809, if that helps in anything (LTSC 2019 installed, so I upgrade it when I want and only manually with an ISO, not when it wants).

Thanks in advance for any help!